# Static Files Migration from development to production error in admin panel

Tags: magento-2.1, composer

I have updated `pub/static/frontend/` from local to live, and getting following error when adding order by admin, Can anybody help me?

Magento Fatal error:

> Interface 'Composer\Package\PackageInterface' not found in
>   /home/username/public_html/livem/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Package/BasePackage.php
>   on line 23

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the composer autoload needs to be generated.

Even if you copied the entire project to production, you still need to run `composer update` command and afterwards, deploy the static content by running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy